# I think my server has become part of a botnet, but ClamAV can't find anything

Tags: cron, malware, clamav

I know virtually nothing about Ubuntu so please be gentle. Recently my server host has contacted me saying they suspect my server is part of a botnet, specifically one that probes TCP ports. They've sent me logs, and it seems I've got a virus.
I've run a full scan using ClamAV and it couldn't find anything. I'm at a loss as to what to do. When I run the `top` command, a process with the command `cron` is using up almost all of the CPU (~99%) so I'm assuming this has something to do with it.
All help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Kill that suspicious command, then backup important things, then reinitialize the server with a fresh OS. You cannot trust it anymore.

Comment: See also [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/395284/how-can-i-kill-minerd-malware-on-an-aws-ec2-instance-compromised-server)

Comment: You can list all the internet connections with `sudo lsof -i`